# CommandParameter always empty wpf MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I want to get the `NamePlaylist`of the `Item` i click on a MenuContext. But the parameter is always empty i don't know why.

It's a Menu in ListView

**XML**

```
<MenuItem Header="Add" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ItemSourcePlaylist}">
   <i:Interaction.Triggers>
      <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
         <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding TestCall}" CommandParameter="{Binding NamePlaylist}"/>
      </i:EventTrigger>
   </i:Interaction.Triggers>
   <MenuItem.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <TextBlock Name="NamePlaylistText" Text="{Binding Path=NamePlaylist}"/>
      </DataTemplate>
   </MenuItem.ItemTemplate>
</MenuItem>
```

**CommandProvider**

```
public class CommandProvider : ICommand
    {
    #region Constructors       

    public CommandProvider(Action<object> execute) : this(execute, null) { }

    public CommandProvider(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute)
    {
        _execute = execute;
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    #endregion

    #region ICommand Members

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return _canExecute != null ? _canExecute(parameter) : true;
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        if (_execute != null)
            _execute(parameter);
    }

    public void OnCanExecuteChanged()
    {
        CanExecuteChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    #endregion

    private readonly Action<object> _execute = null;
    private readonly Predicate<object> _canExecute = null;
    }
```

**Call**

```
public ICommand TestCall { get { return new RelayCommand(obj => this._settingsFunction.TestFunction(obj)); } }
```

**Function**

```
public void TestFunction(object o)
        {
            var tmp = o as string;
            Console.WriteLine(tmp);
            Console.WriteLine("TestMdr");
        }
```

Comment: Is `TestCall` in the same class as `NamePlaylist`? You could change `ItemContainerStyle` and bind command there

Comment: `TestMdr` just rename to `TestCall` is just a variable to call the function.

Comment: Yes but it `TestCall` property (command) of the same class as `NamePlaylist` prioperty? Bacause to me it seems as if `TestCall` is a property of class which holds `ItemSourcePlaylist` list

Comment: Yes `TestCall` and `ItemSourcePlaylist` is in the same class but there are just binding. `NamePlaylist` is in another class `PlaylistDB` contained in `ItemSourcePlaylist` who is a `ObservalleCollection<PlaylistDB>`.

Comment: `InvokeCommandAction` will try to resolve both `Command` and `CommandParameter` bindings in the same binding context

Comment: Oh okay, i see, have you an idea how can i change that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your view model then `ItemSourcePlaylist` and `TestCall` are in one class and `NamePlaylist` is the property of the `ItemSourcePlaylist` item. If that's the case I would suggest use `ItemsContainerStyle` and bind `Command` property to parent's `DataContext` and `CommandParameter` to current item's `DataContext`

```
<MenuItem Header="Add" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ItemSourcePlaylist}">
   <MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
       <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
           <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type MenuItem}}, Path=DataContext.TestCall}"/>
           <Setter Property="CommandParameter" Value="{Binding NamePlaylist}"/>
       </Style>
   </MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
   <MenuItem.ItemTemplate>
       <DataTemplate>
           <TextBlock Name="NamePlaylistText"  Text="{Binding Path=NamePlaylist}"/>
       </DataTemplate>
   </MenuItem.ItemTemplate>
</MenuItem>
```